# How much Ni-chrome wire is used in your average home electric heater?

Tags: heat-transfer

I'm working on an AI Home Temperature controller for my computer science project, and I would like to know how much Ni-chrome wire (in terms of length and diameter) is used in an typical home electric heater?

Comment: Why are you certain that nichrome is used in home heaters?  Shouldn't you be more interested in the net resistance of the element (take a look at line voltage and rated power)?

Comment: A heater is very likely to be a nichrome .The dimensions of the wire are a function of the wattage and service ( a range burner will get "red" hot , but not an electric blanket.)